# How does Wicket setResponsePage() method work?

Tags: java, wicket

When learning about JSP and servlets, I heard about redirect and dispatch. Which of them does Wicket's `setResponsePage()` perform?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What `setResponsePage` does is dependent on a couple of factors: how many times you call setResponsePage, which variant of the setResponsePage you call and what render strategy you use.

You can call `setResponsePage` many times during a request. Wicket uses the last one to work with.

There are two variants of setResponsePage: with a `Page` instance and with a `Page` class and `PageParameters`. The latter sends a redirect to a bookmarkable URL to the browser. The former will, depending on the [render strategy](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/settings/IRequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy.html), either:

- ONE_PASS_RENDER

  - render the page directly to the browser
- REDIRECT_TO_BUFFER

  - render the page to a buffer, send a redirect to the browser (which then retrieves the buffered, rendered markup), or
- REDIRECT_TO_RENDER

  - send a redirect to the browser, which then sends a request to render the page

So the first option is dispatch, the second option is dispatch followed by a redirect, and the third option would be redirect in servlet terms.

Comment: @Martin Dashorst: does the browser see a 302 in REDIRECT_TO_BUFFER?

Comment: Just tried it with my project:

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/som/app/home?14-2.ILinkListener-menu-personalia
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found

So yes, Wicket sends a 302 in that case.

Comment: @Martin Dashorst: thanks, this actualy explains why we have an 302 that takes longer than the 2, reqeust, because of the buffer. Great, another mystery solved ;)

Comment: Thanks, I can now relax knowing that XD. May be someday be some wicket guru like you or Igor. LoL.

Comment: The right render strategy to use may vary case by case. The setting is application-wide. Shouldn't it be (ideally) set per request cycle?

Answer (score 1):

setResponsePage(PageName.class) will redirect the browser to the PageName you need to go.
Make sure that, you have already mount your Page.class to a given path.
For example, in your Application init method, you can mount like this
**mountPage("/home.html", WelcomePage.class);**
then in some other page, when you have a need to go to the home page, you just call like this
 **setResponsePage(WelcomePage.class);**