# Getting parameters from another class in Java

Tags: java, wicket

I Have a simple problem but i can't solve it..
I'm using wicket.
On the web application i have a button (load). When i click that button, some data loads from the web, saves in the DataBase and then loads to the  on the web application (StartPage.html). I have another button for correction that data (edit), and when i click it, EditPage.html loads. So i have just 2 pages. After some corrections on the EditPage.html I click save-button and new data updates in the DataBase and then should be loaded in the  on the web application(StartPage.html).

It's simple, but before i click the "load" button, the  should be clean. So if i'll clean the table before the "load"-click it will be cleaned up every time i click the "edit"-button. i've tried to make some flags, or send parameters to the StartPage, but it seems like a circle.

StartPage should every time loads data but 1st time cleans table but then not. The problem is to send parameters somehow..

I hope it's clear, any suggestions?

**Updated:**

EditPage

```
public class EditPage extends WebPage {
    public EditPage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form") {
                    @Override
                    protected void onSubmit() {
                        // if button "save" clicked
                        PageParameters params = new PageParameters();
                        params.add("flag", "true");
                        setResponsePage(StartPage.class, params);
                    }
        };
    }
}
```

StartPage

```
public class StartPage extends WebPage {
    public StartPage(final PageParameters parameters) {     
            String flag = parameters.getString("flag")
            if (flag=="false")
                // Delete from DB

            Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form") {
                @Override
                protected void onSubmit() {
                    // Load from web to DB      
                }
            };

            // Load from DB
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use this overload of [`RequestCycle.setResponsePage()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/request/cycle/RequestCycle.html#setResponsePage(java.lang.Class, org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters)). Pass it `StartPage.class` or `EditPage.class` respectively, and a `PageParameters` instance you instantiate.

Comment: (It's been a while since I've done Wicket and I don't have a scratchpad project handy, so I can't provide a full answer for this.)

Comment: yeah, but which parameter i can send from EditPage to StartPage? i've tried boolean flag but it's not make it easier.. like if i make **public Boolean flag** and then initialize it, then next time if i'll either send the parameter it will be initialized the same way and parameter won't help

Comment: It's not really clear what exactly it is you've tried from your description. Make a code sample where you include how you're "sending" the parameter in `EditPage`, and how you're retrieving it in  `StartPage`, instead of posting classes with no code in them.

Comment: Also, if it's not clear from the constructors you're actually using in your code and from the signature of `setResponsePage()`: you can't read a field of `EditPage` once you've loaded `StartPage`. (Technically, there's a way to achieve this in Wicket, but it's a bad idea.) You need to send the parameters using the `PageParameters` object, which is kind of like a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally made it like this, but as i can see this is "bad" solution

EditPage

```
public class EditPage extends WebPage {
    public EditPage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form") {
                    @Override
                    protected void onSubmit() {
                        // if button "save" clicked
                        PageParameters params = new PageParameters();
                        params.add("flag", "true");
                        setResponsePage(StartPage.class, params);
                    }
        };
    }
}
```

StartPage

```
public class StartPage extends WebPage {
    public StartPage(final PageParameters parameters) {     

            Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form") {
                @Override
                protected void onSubmit() {
                    // Delete from DB
                    // Load from web to DB
                    // Load from DB     
                }
            };

            if (parameters.getString("flag")!=null)
                // Load from DB
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how you're supposed to do this if you want to do this with a redirect. `PageParameters` represents query parameters that go in the URL, so they have to be strings. For type conversion, you can use [`getAsBoolean()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/value/ValueMap.html#getAsBoolean(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like the following:

```
class StartPage {
    boolean flag;

    StartPage(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}

// in EditPage
void onSubmit() {
    setResponsePage(new StartPage(true));
}
```

(The code you already have is omitted.)

This will **not** do a redirect to a bookmarkable URL. (Which might be what you want.) What it will do exactly is outlined in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10100897/41655).